# Website directory not working?

Tags: html, css

Dumb question I know, but It's really bugging me and I'm hoping some of you guys can tell me where I'm going wrong?

I've built a webpage and I've got a bunch of images on it. I'm trying to set up a web directory but for some reason the images just don't load on the page. I've followed the tutorials I've read down to a tee from what I can see but I'm still having no luck.

Here is some of the code.

```
            <img class= "yogapic1" src="root/img/photos/yogapic1.png" alt="YogaPicture"/>
```

The picture is located in a folder photos inside a folder img. The main folder holding everything in the site is called root.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the html file is located in root?
In that case, remove the `root/` part from the path.

Comment: God I can't believe it was that simple. I'm an absolute moron. Thank you so much. I was making it more complicated than it was by staring at it for so long. Thank you!

Comment: I can't accept an answer for 8 min apparently but I'll give you your tick when I can :D

Answer (score 3):

The img src is wrong you should specify correctly.

```
<img class= "yogapic1" src="./img/photos/yogapic1.png" alt="YogaPicture"/>
```

If your directory sturctr is like this

```
root
  |-- Mainpage.html
  |--img
      |--photos
            |--yogapic1.png
```

Comment: Sorry, for clarification, mainpage.html is inside my root folder.

Comment: <img class= "yogapic1" src="./img/photos/yogapic1.png" alt="YogaPicture"/>

Comment: `img/photos/yogapic1.png` is the same, just shorter.

Answer (score 0):

When serving contents you must refer to the web root, not the folder actually containing your documents. Replace `root/img/photos/yogapic1.png` with `/img/photos/yogapic1.png`.